# @media query not working for iPad in Portrait

Tags: css, ipad, media-queries

I have the following media queries... The Landscape media query is always taking precedence. I tried changing the order of these thinking that if the Portrait one was first it would take precedence, but that did not work. In fact, even when I remove the Landscape media query completely and just leave the Portrait it doesn't work, so it seems like the Portrait media query is broken somehow :S

Here are my two queries:

```
/* iPad Retina, landscape */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
and (orientation : landscape)
and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) { 
#container {
 width: 995px !important;
}


#currentroom_convo {
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
    overflow-y: auto !important;
   overflow-x: hidden !important;
}

.slimScrollBar .ui-draggable {
   opacity: 0 !important;
 }

}


/* iPad Retina, portrait*/
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
and (orientation : portrait)
and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)  { 

#container {
 width: 300px !important;
}



#currentroom_convo {
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
    overflow-y: auto !important;
    overflow-x: hidden !important;
}

.slimScrollBar .ui-draggable {
   opacity: 0 !important;
 }

 div .topbar {
    max-width: 300px !important;
    }

}
```

I have this meta tag in my header:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimal-ui, user-scalable=no">
```

Please note I am using the !important as I need to override some other CSS from a third-party plugin. Removing !important in the landscape query results in no change to the #container element (still doesn't even pick up the Portrait query).

I have tried searching around here but none of the answers seemed to work for me. Thanks :)

Comment: Try removing the space in `div .topbar` under the iPad portrait CSS so that it become `div.topbar`.

Comment: I completely removed the div .topbar style and it still doesnt work :(

Comment: I also removed "and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)" from both of the queries, thinking it wouldn't really many any difference... It didn't... :(

Answer (score 0):

Your approch is wrong. Please note that when you change device orientation forn landscape to portait, your width become height & height become width. In your code your are not changing those values accordingly. Thus as per your condition portait styles apply ***when screen width is between 786px to 1024px***. I think this condition is not satisfied cause ipad resotution width in portait mode is 786px at standard. Thus your styles never get applied.

Also don't use `max-device-width` & `min-device-width` & `max-device-width` instead use `min-width` & `max-width`. The resone behind this is that `max-device-width` gives you width of entire screen, but `max-width` giv you actual width of browser viewport.

Keeping all this things in mind change your code to following:

```
/* iPad Retina, landscape*/
@media only screen and (min-width:768px) and (max-width:1024px) and (orientation:landscape){ 
    /* Styles */
}

/* iPad Retina, portrait*/
@media only screen and (max-width:768px) and (orientation:portrait){ 
    /* Styles */
}
```

Comment: Okay, so I did what you said and got the following results - The landscape style is applied correctly, and is no longer applied to the screen when in portrait, however, no style from the portrait part is being picked up (its all valid css)... thoughts?

Comment: I have tried just putting simple css to change the background color of a div. Landscape works, Portrait is not picked up (but is not using the landscape styling which is good):

Comment: 'code'/* iPad Retina, landscape */
'code'@media only screen 
'code'and (min-width : 768px) 
'code'and (max-width : 1024px) 
'code'and (orientation : landscape) { 
'code'#container {
 'code'background-color: red !important;
'code'}
'code'}

'code'/* iPad Retina, portrait*/
'code'@media only screen 
'code'and (max-width : 768px) 
'code'and (orientation : portrait)  { 
'code'#container {
'code'
 'code' background-color: blue !important;
'code'}
'code'}